# How to calculate the power of an induction motor as in the picture?

Tags: induction-motor

[image: A label of an induction motor]

Here is motor of an washing machine. As shown in the picture, it is a 220VAC/50Hz, 135W, and 1.3A induction motor. There are voltage, power, and the current. What I understand about how to calculate the power of a motor is **P=V * I** or **P=V^2/R**. But as the available information on the name plate are V, P, and I, then we use the first formula. But what I don't understand is, how the power become 135 watt? If the V=220VAC and the I=1.3A, should not it be **220V*1.3A = 286 watt**? If it is, then how the power of the **135 watt**? I understand there will be loss and hence we call efficiency. But efficiency should not be that low, just 47%. Efficiency of an induction motor should be around 90%. What do I miss so I don't understand the power information on that name plate?

I checked my another 3 induction motors, also motors of washing machines. All are 220VAC/50Hz, and their power rating is as following: ***1.5A & 150W***, ***0.75A & 60W***, and ***0.8A & 70W***. The all consistent like the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't calculate power for motors with the "P=V^2/R=I*V" equations. Those are equations are used when the load in question is resistive. Your motor is reactive, therefore, you must also account for a power factor of less than unity.

The power factor for your motor will be a bit over 0.47. Power or the motor is calculated as P=I*V*PF, or 135W=1.3A*220VAC*0.47. You can use the same formula for resistive loads while using a power factor equal to 1.

The reason for the discrepancy is that inductive loads have a current magnitude that lags the voltage. This causes a displacement in the current through the motor with the voltage across it. Only real power is transferred when the voltage and current magnitudes are the same polarity.

Comment: Yes, the R should be Z. But apart from it, it will not change the calculation as I didn't use it. Power factor in my country is strictly maintained 0.9. As we are archipelago, in some other remote islands with their own water power plant. that PF can be as low as 0.8, but in most main islands the PF is 0.9. I don't think any country with power factor is at that low.

Comment: I can't speak for your country's regulations,  but possibly that min. PF limit only matters after certain Power/Current limit is exceeded? Also, that motor is part of a washing machine, therefore, it's whole washing machine that gets certified to the standards; the motor is just a component. What does the nameplate on the washing machine say with respect to Amps, Volts, and Watts?

Comment: @AirCraftLover I'm sorry you don't understand.

Comment: @AirCraftLover your comment makes no sense both in content and in the use of the English language. The motor determines it’s power factor, not the generating station. Since the motor looks like a capacitor run type single phase motor, the capacitor makes a significant difference to the power factor. On a 3 phase motor, this capacitor does not exist, so you cannot compare.